# Using env variables in template files

Tags: angular, typescript

Is it possible to use env variables in template files?

I'm currently trying this syntax:

```
<img class="preview-image" src="{{environment.assets + item.image}}" />
```

which results in the following error:

> Identifier 'environment' is not defined. The component
>   declaration, template variable declarations, and element references do
>   not contain such a member

I have tried importing it in my component.ts file, `import { environment } from './../../../../environments/environment';` but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 32):

Just define public `environment` variable in controller with the value, then you can access it in the template:

```
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

export class AppComponent {

  environment = environment;

}
```

Answer (score 15):

I recently wanted to do the same and I came up with a pipe solution that works in every template without needing to change its .ts file:

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
import {environment} from '../../environments/environment';

@Pipe({name: 'env'})
export class EnvPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(variable: keyof typeof environment): any {
    return environment[variable];
  }
}
```

Then, in your HTML, just use:

```
<span>{{'variableName' | env}}</span>
```

In your case:

```
<img class="preview-image" src="{{'assets' | env}}{{item.image}}" />
```

Make sure to add the pipe component to your `app.module.ts`

Comment: I really like this solution as it prevents repeating the code in every component. The one thing I suggest changing is the type of `variable` from `string` to `keyof typeof environment`. This fixes some strict TypeScript checks.

Comment: Good point, I integrated your suggestions. Thanks.